# plutil error 998 when trying to convert binary to XML

Tags: windows, xml, binary-files, plist

EDIT: Clarification.

I'd like to read the contents of a .plist file on Windows.

I tried with VS Code but it's [not ideal](https://snag.gy/Jf03oV.jpg) and it says "File seems to be binary and cannot be opened as text" so I googled a bit and multiple sources said that I need to [convert it to XML](https://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Converting_Binary_Plists) to be able to view it.
I read that plutil (which is downloaded with iTunes for Windows) can do that with this command but

```
plutil -convert xml1 file.plist
```

results in

```
plutil.exe[10768:1724] error reading 490 bytes from fd 3, error was 998
```

I searched a bit and some people have error 998 when installing/opening iTunes and reinstalling worked for them but reinstalling doesn't work for plutil.

Does anybody know how to solve this error 998? So far I didn't have much luck solving it with whatever Google suggested.

Or how else can I view plist files on Windows if editors don't work? (I tried some free plist editors I found but they either couldn't open it due to some character encoding issues or had the same result as VS Code.)

Comment: Everything is binary. When some one says that a file is binary, they are just covering up there ignorance (they just don't know how to interpret the file. There is nothing shameful about this, so just say “I don't know”, instead of pretending to know something “Ah yes this one has bits, some are 1s and some are 0s”.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Then I'll pass your comment along, sending feedback in VS Code asking them to change the "File seems to be binary and cannot be opened as text" message because it's ignorant. But I think the error I get with plutil will persist. Regardless, thank you for your comment.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you are actually trying to do, nor what connection iTunes has to the issue. Nor, in fact what you perceive the difference is between a .plist & an .xml - they're both flat text files.

Comment: @Tetsujin Right, I left out some steps so I wouldn't write a wall of text, sorry. My initial (main) issue is not being able to view the plist file. After VS Code (and Excel and any other plist editor) couldn't read it I googled a bit and multiple sources said I'd need to convert the plist file to XML if it's binary and apparently iTunes for Windows has this program called [plutil](https://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Converting_Binary_Plists) which can do that with that command. And this command gives me the 998 error.

Comment: What happens if you just open it in a regular text editor? a .plist is just a text file, nothing more. Basically, it's a special-purpose xml. They all start with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">`

Comment: @Tetsujin Every text editor I tried turns up what's on the [screenshot](https://snag.gy/Jf03oV.jpg) (under the "not ideal" text in my post). Nothing readable. I tried with Excel because some sources said it can read it but every character encoding is similar to what's on the screenshot.

Comment: OK, so it is binary - it's actually opening just fine, it's simply not human-readable. You will need to open it in an app that actually knows what it is, where it came from & what it's for. You can't translate it if you don't know how it was initially encoded.

Comment: These plist files are for assets in a mobile game. The pictures are usually characters with 5 different emotions but the head is detached from the body. Every .png has a .plist with the same name. I suspected that the game uses the information in the .plist files when it's changing which emotion to show and was hoping that if I get to read the contents of the plists there's some info about coordinates or something and I don't have to manually adjust it which can take a lot of time.
So what do you think I could do to read these?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the directory for Apples' application support to your PATH.

You can set it for just that CMD session like this

```
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Apple Application Support\;%PATH%
```

or permanently in control panel -> system

---

It worked fine for me. 
There are a few of them on my system

[C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Apple Application Support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsdSc.png)

The same version but x64 I assume is also found in 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Apple Application Support and 
C:\windows

I also have an older one in
[C:\Program Files (x86)\Safari\Apple Application Support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZNxU.png)

Here are some other ideas

You could also use notepad++ and add in the plist plugin.

Several tools in GIT you could use for instance

iPhone-Backup-Analyzer - Mario Piccinelli

Comment: I added it to the environment variables if that's what you're talking about otherwise I would've gotten an error for the plutil command. So that doesn't seem to be the problem but something with Windows, I asked my friend to try this method on his Windows PC and he got the same error 998.